# Laravel-Excel is updating permission each time

Tags: php, excel, laravel, laravel-excel

Laravel-Excel is unable to move the generated file to the temp location. Laravel-Excel is updating file permission.

Here is error:

```
ErrorException: fopen(/storage/framework/export/laravel-excel-CgOSec4XiXr3vry7juut47IAyVDV9eiB.csv): Failed to open stream: Permission denied in /vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Writer/BaseWriter.php:128
```

If I change the permission, it works only for one time. After that, it throws the same issue. I have to update the permissions each time. It seems like Laravel-excel is updating the permission.

GitHub Repo:
https://github.com/SpartnerNL/Laravel-Excel

Comment: You need to provide more information. What are the permissions on the target directory (/storage/framework/export)? Is this being executed as a web server process or cli? What manual permissions changes have you been making each time to get it to work?

Comment: @user1191247 folder permission is 644 and changed to 664. It only work after I change to 664?

Comment: I have discovered that Laravel-Excel is creating files with 644 permissions, but they need to be set to 664 for proper access. Would it be possible to update the permissions to 664?

Comment: @Vijay Folder permission is not under package control, Laravel default file permission is 644, modify your `config/filesystems.php` add setting on it, details see [here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/filesystem#local-files-and-visibility)